# Get value from input on modal box using external library

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using a built in modal popup from [this](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__message_boxes.html#modalbox) library.

I've placed an input field in the modal, and I would like to get the value of that field on click of the ok button. Here's what my code looks like:

```
    gantt.modalbox({
      title: 'Rename',
      text: `<input type="text" #rename>`,
      buttons: [
        { label: 'Ok', value: 'ok' }
      ],
      callback: result => {
        // if 'ok' is clicked
        if (result === 'ok') {
          // get value from input here
        }
      }
    });
```

I've tried using a element ref but I wasn't able to get that working. Can anyone suggest a way to get the value from the input in the modal that I dynamically created?

```
text: `<input type="text" #rename>`
```

Comment: The library you linked doesn't seem to support that option - only programmable buttons that you give to the modal can you get back as a result..

Comment: can you explain in which format you are expecting result of modal. may be after seeing an example, we find more accurate solution.

Comment: i just want to be able to access what was typed into the input field that i put into the modal. i want to use that value in the if block at the bottom of the code @FarhatZaman